# Generate .dto.ts on build

Tags: typescript, servicestack

As a part of a development process, we update .dto.ts often. But it turns out that sometimes api is changed and developer forgot to update .dto.ts before submitting pull request.
Is it possible to update .dto.ts files every time you rebuild project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install [servicestack-cli](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-cli) npm script, you can update your TypeScript DTOs in your npm-based projects by running:

```
typescript-ref
```

In the same directory where your `dtos.ts` are.

To run them from Visual Studio build event you may need to create a `dtos.cmd` file that calls node.exe to run your npm scripts, e.g:

```
node npm run typescript-ref
```

If it can't find node.exe you can use the full path:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node" npm run typescript-ref
```

Although due to the way [Add ServiceStack Reference works](http://docs.servicestack.net/add-servicestack-reference#how-it-works), it's not enough for the project to be built, it must also be running (e.g. in IIS Express) as the npm script calls a ServiceStack Service to generate the TypeScript DTOs.